# short cut technique for finding null value from Dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdictionary

I have 100 key and value in nsmutabledictornary and i want to check that any value have null or not. Do you have any short function or technique?

I don't want to multiple line code like check every key and value.  Your answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This code will give you the set of keys which have (non)null values.  You can't store actual `nil` values in a dictionary, so `[NSNull null]` is assumed.  The predicate is trivially alterable to any other condition.

```
NSDictionary *d = @{ @"a" : @"1", @"b" : [NSNull null] };

NSSet *nullKeys = [d keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    return [d[key] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]];
}];

NSSet *nonnullKeys = [d keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    return [d[key] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] == NO;
}];
```

From here, you can use the keys to generate a corresponding dictionary, if needed.

```
NSMutableDictionary *nonNullDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[d enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([nonnullKeys contains:key]) {
        nonNullDict[key] = obj;
    }
}];
```

If you don't need a separate list of keys, and just need the filtered dictionary, skip the first step and modify the second part to read as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary *nonNullDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[d enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull null]] == NO) {
        nonNullDict[key] = obj;
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Write category on NSDictionary it will provide you null free dictionary. Here is the category I have written for myself.

code for .h file (interface)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (CheckNull)
{

}

- (NSDictionary *)nullFreeDictionary;

@end
```

Code for .m file. (implementation)

```
#import "NSDictionary+CheckNull.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (CheckNull)
- (NSDictionary *) nullFreeDictionary
{
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [self mutableCopy];
    for (NSString *key in tempDictionary.allKeys) {
        NSString *value = [tempDictionary valueForKey:key];
        if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            if (value == (id)[NSNull null] || value == nil || value.length == 0) {
                [tempDictionary setValue:@"" forKey:key];
            }
        }
    }
    return tempDictionary;
}
```

Call null free method on your dictionary using above category.

```
  NSDictionary *dict = [dict nullFreeDictionary];
```

Comment: If you're not using predicates and filtering, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Avi you can't say its wrong. I have written my own category. What actually filtering and predicates do on backend? I iterated through all the keys and set empty values against them. So that you don't need to apply any check on each and every key in your code manually. Further more if you have any better solution you are more than welcome to put it forward.

Comment: I meant wrong in terms of efficiency and using the framework to do the heavy lifting.  If you're filtering through use of nested loops, you should look for another option.  The Foundation collection classes all have builtin filtering capability.

Comment: Am i using nested loop?

Comment: Sorry, misread one of the if statements as another loop.  Still, the framework will happily do the work for you.

Answer (score -1):

//To remove NULL from Dictionary

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)removeNullFromDictionary : (NSMutableDictionary *)dict
{
    //    if (![dict isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]])
    //    {
    //    }
    dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];

    for (NSString * key in [dict allKeys])
    {
        if ([dict[key] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        {
            [dict setValue:@"" forKey:key];
        }
        else if ([dict[key] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]||[dict[key] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            dict[key] = [self removeNullFromDictionary:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict[key]]];
        }
        else if ([dict[key] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]||[dict[key] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            dict[key] = [self removeNullFromArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:dict[key]]];
        }
    }

    return dict;
}
```

//To remove NULL from Array

```
-(NSMutableArray *)removeNullFromArray : (NSMutableArray *)arr
{
    //    if (![arr respondsToSelector:@selector(addObject:)])
    //    {
    //        arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arr];
    //    }
    arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arr];
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt<[arr count]; cnt++)
    {
        if ([arr[cnt] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        {
            arr[cnt] = @"";
        }
        else if ([arr[cnt] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]||[arr[cnt] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            arr[cnt] = [self removeNullFromDictionary:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:arr[cnt]]];
        }
        else if ([arr[cnt] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]||[arr[cnt] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            arr[cnt] = [self removeNullFromArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr[cnt]]];
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```